# I'm having issues stopping tiny cuts and uneven print quality in my prints ever since I upgraded my printer

Tags: print-quality

It has been a few months of trial and error trying to work this out. I made the printer succeed in printing normally, but the quality is terrible. These tiny cuts appear in every print as well as uneven walls that feel bumpy. Does anyone have any tips to fix this?

Printer specs:

- Ender 3 v2
- Sprite pro extruder
- CR touch
- Pro software

[image: Photo of a 3D benchy with what look like tiny cuts randomly up the model]

[image: Photo of a 3D printed model with small horizontal cuts along the perimeter]

Comment: What changes did you make in the upgrade? The problem you're seeing is missed extrusions, which usually mean the extruder is skipping steps or the filament is slipping in the extruder gear.

Comment: The upgrades are a sprite pro extruder, cr-touch bed leveling, and pro software.

Comment: You upgraded from the original bowden to the sprite direct drive? If so, and if you didn't change your retraction settings to ones suitable for the direct drive, that would explain the problems you're seeing.

Comment: You have any good settings for this extruder? I'm having trouble finding an exact setting for this exact printhead.

Comment: No, I don't use a Sprite, but generally direct drives need a much lower retraction length because the filament path is mostly or entirely rigid, and much shorter. If you're using linear advance and it's properly calibrated, retraction length should be no more than 1 mm for direct drive, and possibly as low as 0.3 mm or even lower. If you don't have linear advance, it might need to be a little over 1 mm.

Comment: I changed the retraction distance to .8mm and it helped dramatically, Now there is the issue that around the bottom of a Benchy test there are blob-like inaccuracies. Do I have my Minimum distance before retraction set too low?

Comment: Min distance before retraction should ideally be set at 0 or at least less than the nozzle width. Anything else will turn small details into a mess of strings. So I don't think that's the problem. It might just be moist filament now, or something else. Can you post a pic or ask a new question about the blobs?